# W3C validation error with data-href

Tags: jquery, html, w3c

I am getting one validation error due to my use of data-href="" in the context of making a whole DIV clickable. The JS and HTML is below. What could I do to make this W3C compliant?

JQUERY

```
$(function(){
$(".linked").click(function(){
window.location = $(this).attr("data-href");
return false;
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="" data-href="link.html"></div>
```

Comment: What's the complete HTML you're passing to the validator? I plugged your div in a valid HTML5 doc and the validator passed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If possible, you should consider using a [doctype](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html) that supports `data-*` attributes. For HTML5, that's:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: @Christoph. It's not a doctype at all... :-)

Comment: ..or any valid doctype, for that matter. Thanks for the catch--fixed now!

Comment: actually, this is the ONLY doctype supporting `data-*` attributes, since its part of the html5 spec;)

Answer (score 2):

Since `data-*` is part of the `HTML5`specification, you need to use the html5-doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Any other doctype will parse your site according to HTML4 or XMHTML-Rules, where the `data-*` Attribute is invalid.

edit:

You should always start your html with the proper doctype. Since `<!DOCTYPE html>`triggers standards-mode in all browser, this is "the only right way" except you really want XHTML for example (although I can't see a reason why you should).

edit2:

You might want to consider using an `a` anchor-tag instead, since it already has an href and is considered to be clickable?

Comment: Edit2: Can you explain that a bit more, I'm confused. Is that a better way of making the entire DIV clickable?

Comment: Yes of course. Since you are using an element, that has to have a href-attribute and should be clickable, you could use an `a`-tag INSTEAD of an `div`. This would - semantically - make more sense. Also, pseudo-classes like `:hover` and `:active` are said to be more performant on `a`-tags.

Answer (score 1):

*data-* attributes are part of the HTML5 specification so if your document does not have the HTML5 Doctype, the validator will produce an error.

In the meantime, there is no problem of using those attribute with an HTML4 doctype, the browser will do nothing with it and you'll be able to work with them - the page will simply not validate to the W3C validator.

Comment: I changed the doctype to <!DOCTYPE HTML> which now allowed the data-href to validate? However, I coded my page in HTML4. Is it a problem having HTML 4 in a HTML 5 doctype or is that not an issue?

Answer (score -1):

You cool with adding the attribute through jQuery? Or do we need a more dynamic solution?

```
$(".linked").attr('data-href', 'link.html').click(function(){
  window.location = $(this).attr("data-href");
  return false;
});
```

*also*:

Considering that this *isn't* a WC3 compliant method have you thought about moving this into the Title attribute? Remove the '.html'line, and in your click function:

HTML:

```
<div class="" title="link"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".linked").click(function(){
  var dataHref = $(this).attr('title');
  window.location = dataHref.html;
  return false;
});
```

Then again, we run into issues with propagation. I don't know how your links are being propagated, whether you hard-code them or you dynamically create them with server side script, so the latter and previous solutions still not might be good enough for you.

**I was downvoted, as the OP said that the solution provided did not work -- The solution provided works completely fine. Please see the fiddle below, and make sure you don't have errors in your javascript before you downvote someone.**

> http://jsfiddle.net/n68A8/

Comment: I have multiple DIVs that I need to be clickable, so a more dynamic solution would be better. I guess.

Comment: If you're not interested in changing data-href to the title attribute, and you want to maintain validation, you can add the attribute with jQuery after DOM load. Wc3 validator's don't look at DOM changes, and jQuery performs all attribute changes *after* DOM load when in the $(document).ready(function(){ scope.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're not doing it right. Please see my fiddle, Andy.