# w3 validator - facebook widget

Tags: html, facebook, validation, widget, w3c

I have erors for Facebook widget

Widget is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/..mypage" data-width="364" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="true"></div>
```

Error message:
there is no attribute "data-href"

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/
```

Error message:
there is no attribute "data-width"

```
…-" data-width="364" data-show-faces="true" data-stream…
```

Comment: _Custom data attributes_ are a feature of HTML5 – so either use that, or just _ignore_ these errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [w3c Validation error message - Facebook widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529363/w3c-validation-error-message-facebook-widget)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a doctype that supports the data-href etc.
[W3C validation error with data-href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774376/w3c-validation-error-with-data-href)

Perhaps try
`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Is this not the same as the question you asked yesterday?

[w3c Validation error message - Facebook widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529363/w3c-validation-error-message-facebook-widget)